# test if a browser has a certain cookie

Tags: javascript, cookies

I have been working on a website and I want a greeting message to come up if it is the first time the person has been on the site. I know how to create the cookie (let's call it iwashere). I just need a way to test if the browser has the cookie.

Regards,
Thomas

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30888022/2025923 will help you

Comment: If you know how to set a cookie you should also be able to read it. It's even easier to get than to set.

Comment: ok (see how I got by the letter measurer?)